# How to interact with native apps using appium-flutter-driver & webdriverIO project

Tags: flutter, appium, webdriver-io

I'm using `appium-flutter-driver` & `webdriverIO` to automate the flutter mobile app.

I have a use case in my application where clicking on

- `Mail us` button opens `Gmail app` with subject, body
- `Call us` button opens `Dailer app` with phone number

I want assert/verify that gmail/phone app is opened. either one of following is fine

- verifying that gmail/phone app package name
- verifying the subject, content in gmail compose screen is also fine

I see here https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver that

```
await driver.switchContext('NATIVE_APP');
await (await driver.$('~fab')).click();
```

- what is `~fab` means here?
- How to find elements using `ID`, `text`, `class` in this case and perform `click`, `enterText`, etc operations?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `~fab` means. But the available finders are mentioned [here](https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver#finders), with links to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders-class.html). The available commands are mentioned [here](https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver#commands), with links to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver-class.html).

An example of a finder by semantics label with a click:

```
element = FlutterElement(self.driver, FlutterFinder().by_semantics_label('Back'))
element.click()
```

An example of entering text:

```
driver.execute_script('flutter: enterText')
```

Got these examples from [here](https://medium.com/tauk-blog/automating-flutter-apps-using-appium-55a8d74dbe31).